# How to get id of view in parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

how to get view id in parent layout? I can get view by id, but if I can get id by view?

Update:
What i do

I create and add to LinearLayout some View:

```
  LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout();

// add few View
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    MyView mView = new MyView(this);

 // MyView has time field, and at creation time MyView stack ordered by time-field
    mView.setTime(anyTime+i);

 // When I click on mView - opens screen where I can modify time
    mView.setOnClickListener(listener);

 ll.addView(mView)
}
```

So after mView modifying I won to move mView in correct place, for this I need know index in LinearLayout (ll) of current MyView, index of previous and next MyView

Update 2:
Maybe I need List where I will sort MyView and redraw all LinearLayout

Comment: It's look like I've founded answer. I am writting it bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int ViewGroup.indexOfChild(View child)  will help me. I will write more, when I test all decigion.

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT"
android:layout_width="FILL_PARENT"
/>
```

---

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
String imageName = "image1"// Your ImageView id name
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "id", getPackageName());
```

[getIdentifier Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Hope it helps you out!!

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view -  without ID you can't access the views.U can go for tag.for that In view you can setTag() and you can getTag().we can use tag also as ID somecases.